# How to support backwards compatibility with the changes to the Accept header handling in Rails 2.3.4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http-headers

In Rails 2.3.4, the way `Accept` headers are handled has changed:

http://github.com/rails/rails/commit/1310231c15742bf7d99e2f143d88b383c32782d3

> **We won't Accept it**
>
> The way in which Rails handles incoming Accept headers has been updated. This was primarily due to the fact that web browsers do not always seem to know what they want ... let alone are able to consistently articulate it. So, Accept headers are now only used for XHR requests or single item headers - meaning they're not requesting everything. If that fails, we fall back to using the params[:format].
>
> It's also worth noting that requests to an action in which you've only declared an XML template will no longer be automatically rendered for an HTML request (browser request). This had previously worked, not necessarily by design, but because most browsers send a catch-all Accept header ("*/*"). So, if you want to serve XML directly to a browser, be sure to provide the :xml format or explicitly specify the XML template (render "template.xml").

I have an active API which is being used by many clients who are all sending both a `Content-Type` and an `Accept` header, both set to `application/xml`.  This works fine, but my testing under Rails 2.3.4 demonstrates that this no longer works -- I get a 403 Unauthorised response.  Remove the `Accept` header and just sending `Content-Type` works, but this clearly isn't an acceptable solution since it will require that all my clients re-code their applications.

If I proceed to deploy to Rails 2.3.4 all the client applications which use the API will break.  How can I modify my Rails app such that I can continue to serve existing API requests on Rails 2.3.4 without the clients having to change their code?

Comment: Why are your clients setting content-type: application/xml? Are they sending XML data along with their get/post requests? Isn't the accept header used to specify the formats you will accept, and content-type used to define the format you're sending?

Comment: Does this error happen for all of your routes/verbs? If you pass application/xml content and accept header to verbs expecting data do you still get this error? I can't reproduce your problem. More info would be appreciated.

Comment: Use of the Content-type was originally added to the API but as you suggest isn't strictly necessary -- it's the Accept header which is used by Rails to determine which Mime Type to respond to.   I'm not able to reproduce this locally in my dev environment.  Could it actually be an Apache issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Embarrassingly enough, this actually turned out to be an Apache configuration issue.  Once I resolved this, everything worked as expected.  Sorry about that.

As coderjoe correctly pointed out, setting the `Content-Type` header isn't necessary at all -- only setting the `Accept` header.

Comment: If you don't mind, posting a quick blurb about the Apache configuration might help future users running into the same problem. :) Glad you found the problem!

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly the problem is in the Request headers. You can simply add a custom Rack middleware that corrects it.

Quick idea:

```
class AcceptCompatibility
  def initialize(app)
    @app = app
  end

  def call(env)
    if env['Accept'] == "application/xml" && env['Content-Type'] == "application/xml"
      # Probably an API call
      env.delete('Accept')
    end
    @app.call(env)
  end
end
```

And then in your environment.rb

```
require 'accept_compatibility'
config.middleware.use AcceptCompatibility
```

Comment: Won't this solution keep you from being able to POST XML data to a controller while asking for an XML response?