# Simple Question: Is Rails 2.3.4 backward compatible with Rails 2.3.2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

A client is indicating that the Rails version I have installed on my Ubuntu servers (2.3.4) is not backward-compatible with the older Version 2.3.2.

I want to know if that is true or not before I attempt to install the older Rails.

Comment: You might want to take a look at this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1612633/how-to-support-backwards-compatibility-with-the-changes-to-the-accept-header-hand

Comment: Whya re they saying it is not backwards compatible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the beauty of rubygems. just install both versions and have them specify which version in their environment file problem solved who cares if its compatible or not

Answer (score 0):

New features are never backward compatible.

Comment: Yeah but there can be some backward incompatible changes between two different versions. It's not new features. It's (usually unused) features removal. One concrete example is here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1612633/how-to-support-backwards-compatibility-with-the-changes-to-the-accept-header-hand

Comment: That pretty clearly wasn't the problem that led to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it is possible that you are using features that are **only** available on version 2.3.4 , and therefore they're **not** on version 2.3.2.

Check its changelog to see the differences.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading between even minor Rails versions often causes problems with old apps.

That said, 2.3.4 is the current recommended stable version so it would probably be worth biting the bullet and getting the 2.3.2 app running on it. Probably won't take very long, if you've got a decent test suite.

Answer (score 0):

There are also a few of bugs that are introduced. Like this one I found involving [named scopes using includes.](https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/2998-named_scope-ignores-include-option) That was introduced in 2.3.3 and wasn't fixed in 2.3.4

Answer (score 0):

2.3.2 => 2.3.4 has been the most painless upgrade so far for us (large app with lots of legacy, rails 1.x code).

The only [major issues we had were with `after_initialize` vs `exists?`](https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994-ruby-on-rails/tickets/3165-activerecordmissingattributeerror-after-update-to-rails-v-234#ticket-3165-21).

It all varies app by app. If you are hosting a client's app, then you should provide gems of all rails versions (they will happily sit side by side (90% of the time)).