# How to solve a ruby on rails version discrepancy (backward/forward compatability)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database-schema, dbvisualizer

I'm new to Ruby/Ruby on Rails and I'm working with [project fedena](http://www.projectfedena.org/) which runs on Rails [2.3.5](http://www.projectfedena.org/install). I looked around for a rails schema visualizer.. but I found that there are only [some gems](http://railroad.rubyforge.org/) that support rails 1.x and [others](https://github.com/preston/railroady) that support rails 3.x.

Is it possible to get a RoR application that was built with a certain RoR version in mind and compile it again for another version of RoR? I've been researching about backward/forward compatibility in Ruby and I'm getting [un-encouraging](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1626182/766570) results.  It seems there are significant difference across the various RoR releases.

Comment: i noticed that the latest version of project fedena was released in 2012, long after ruby on rails 3 was released.. is there a reason why they'd stick with an older version of rails (ie 2.x)?

Comment: I found [this](http://blog.brzezinka.eu/webmaster-tips/ruby/ror-railroad-plugin-with-rails-2-3-5-on-windows-error).. but it's for windows.. i'm looking for mac

Answer (score 0):

I saw your problem i had it too but i used this:

```
  GO TO /project/config/environment
  and add this code


  Rails::Initializer.run do |config|
    config.time_zone = 'UTC'
    config.gem 'GEM_NAME', :version => '~> 2.3.5'
  end
```

THIS WILL HELP YOU WITH YOUR TESTING